# AWS Application Load Balancer not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, amazon-ecs, amazon-elb

I have a EC2 cluster with just one EC2 instance, where two services are running:

- api1, listening at port 8080
- api2, listening at port 9090

If I make requests against EC2 instance and those ports, both APIs work fine.

Now, I want to create a load balancer so I can make requests against `http://{load_balancer_ip}/api1` and `http://{load_balancer_ip}/api2`, but I'm not able to.

I have created two target groups, both with just one instance (the only one I have)

1. `TargetGroup1`: Port 8080 and the EC2 instance registered on port 8080
2. `TargetGroup2`: Port 9090 and the EC2 instance registered on port 9090

Then, I have created a load balancer with one listener on port 80 and these two path rules:

- When `/api1`, forward to `TargetGroup1`
- When `/api2`, forward to `TargetGroup2`

When I make requests against `http://{load_balancer_ip}/api1` or `http://{load_balancer_ip}/api2` nothing happens; I don't get any response.

What am I missing?

Comment: What are the security groups you attached to the EC2 instance and to the load balancer ?

Comment: 1: Load Balancer will provide you DNS, not IP.  2: There is a Listener Rule, Where you need to provide the path followed by the target group. Have you Checked with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found what's happening thanks to this question's first comment:

[AWS Application Load Balancer (ALB) path based routing not functioning as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45216486/aws-application-load-balancer-alb-path-based-routing-not-functioning-as-expect)

Load balancer is not rewriting the URL and my APIs are listening at `/`, but load balancer is redirecting all the path `/api1`.

Solved!

(I couldn't mark it as duplicated because question above does not have any accepted answer)